# DOVECOT not allowed to log in using too low UNIX UID

Tags: linux, email, email-server, dovecot

I found this error on mail.log

```
May 13 22:11:37 vmi2115 dovecot: dovecot: User admin@example.net not allowed to log in using too low UNIX UID 103(postfix) (see first_valid_uid in config file)
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

See first_valid_uid in config file.